# Can you set a dictionary value dependant on another dictionary entry?

Tags: python, dictionary, dependencies, key-value

Here's the thought:

```
dict1 = {key1:3, key2:5, key3:key1+key2}
# so key3 relate to the value: 8 (3+5)
dict1.update({key2:6})
# key3 will now relate to the value: 9 (3+6)
```

I'm trying to avoid updating more entries than necessary as well as building new relations of key-value that's based on values that has already been calculated in a series of lookups and updates while comparing values of relations. The dictionarys' hashability is crucial to get me a more or less constant time on lookup.

Comment: You mean, you want to dynamically update the value for `key3`? You mean `dict1[key1] + dict1[key2]`, don't you?

Comment: No such way. For the general case, you'd need to build a dependency graph and use `lambda`s or something with a dict subclass to recompute all dependent values when another value changes. It'd be something like what spreadsheet software does.

Comment: Also take a look at dict `viewobjects`. I can't see how to apply them to your requirements but maybe you find a way: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: You could build all that machinery if you wanted, but you'd need much more than just a plain dict, and the syntax could get cumbersome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a general solution but roughly works for your example:

```
class DynamicDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super(DynamicDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        return eval(value, self) if isinstance(value, str) else value

>>> d = DynamicDict(key1=3, key2=5, key3='key1+key2')
>>> d.update({'key2': 6})
>>> d['key3']
9
```

Comment: I'm surprised `eval` actually invokes the real `__getitem__` method, rather than using an internal call. As long as the expressions are relatively simple, this works pretty well. If the expressions grow more complex, or if the dependency graph becomes nontrivial, this could result in nasty amounts of recomputation. It's worth noting that `eval` adds a `__builtins__` entry to the `globals` dict you pass it, which could confuse code that doesn't expect that.

Comment: In a more complex use case, you could augment this with memoization, perhaps taking advantage of the `__missing__` method to speed up the case where the value has already been computed, and invalidate cached dependent values when entries they depend on change. I could see this generalizing pretty well... but as long as it only needs to handle input complexity on the order of what the question includes, it's not worth all the extra code and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a subclass of `dict` and overriding the `__getitem__` method:

```
class My_dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'key3':
            return self['key1'] + self['key2']
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

dict1 = My_dict(key1=3, key2=5)
print dict1['key3']               #prints 8
dict1.update({'key2':6})         
print dict1['key3']               #prints 9
```

Comment: I agree, best way IMHO.

Comment: Works for this specific case, but doesn't generalize very well if you need to change the formula or what keys depend on what other keys. Building a general solution isn't simple, though.

Comment: This does not absolutely work - one wqould have to hard code each formula inside the "getitem" function - check Mathew's answer for the generic, few lines way, depending on eval. That works.

Comment: @jsbueno What if I wanted to define a key like `key4='A'` in that solution, and then try to access it, it won't work. IMO it's better to explicitly define the conditions than using `eval`.

Comment: That solution, in case you have not seen, is 3 line function - of course the matter has to be a little bnit more well thought to allow access to non-formula values, and also to retrieve the original expressions, if they are wanted. This does not change the fact the  proposal defined in this answer is an awkward anti-pattern, as terrible as it can be.