# Variable in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
A = {"a": 1, "b":2}
```

And I want to write, instead of above initialization, a variable instead of `2` that is 4 times `a`'s value that updates if `a`'s value changes.

I cannot do this:

```
A={"a": 1, "b": 4*A["a"]}
```

How can I handle this?

‡: Here in my code,

```
flight = {
    "dest": "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for n in xrange(3)),
    "from": "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for n in xrange(3)),
    "not_available_seats": [],
    "available_seats": 50,
    "uid": uid,
    #"price": 10,
    "date": datetime.datetime.now()
}
flight["price"] = lambda: (51 - flight["available_seats"])*10
```

So when print flight(), I get error.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, within the `{}` `A` doesn't exist yet, so `A["a"]` has no meaning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you set a dictionary value dependant on another dictionary entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468401/can-you-set-a-dictionary-value-dependant-on-another-dictionary-entry)

Comment: You edited the question, but now it's confusing. If you initialize A with static values, and then try to re-initialize it with a dynamic value (as reflected in your question), it will work fine. If you instead ONLY try to initialize it self-referentially, then it won't work (see @jpp's link).

Comment: Could you do two assignments? Ie `A={"a": 1}; A["b"]=4*A["a"];`. At this point, A exists, and contains a `"a"` key with a value.

Comment: @Drise, the issue is the link is broken, i.e. updating key 'a' does not update key 'b'. The first thing the user should ask is why is it crucial to have these values linked dynamically in a dictionary. The solutions (subclassing dict) are technical for novice coders.

Comment: Do you want it to always be 4 * a? Even if you change a?

Comment: @chrisz Yes, right. When a changes, b should also change.

Comment: @dtoprakhisar In that case, my answer will not do what you need.

Comment: @dtoprakhisar You can't do that with a dict. You'll need a custom class with properties.

Comment: @dtoprakhisar, If possible can you briefly explain why this is necessary? Sometimes this is an X-Y problem. It's rarely, if ever, necessary (in my experience) to require what you are asking.

Comment: @jpp I too smell an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I look at this problem the more I believe you want an object-oriented solution.

Here is one implementation:

```
import random, string
from datetime import datetime

class Flight(object):

    def __init__(self, dest, origin, not_available_seats, available_seats, uid, date):
        self.dest = dest
        self.origin = origin
        self.not_available_seats = not_available_seats
        self.available_seats = available_seats
        self.uid = uid
        self.date = date
        self.price = (51 - self.available_seats) * 10

    def set_available_seats(self, available_seats):
        self.available_seats = available_seats
        self.price = (51 - self.available_seats) * 10
        return None
```

You can create a class instance as easily as adding a dictionary item:

```
F1 = Flight("".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for n in range(3)),
            "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for n in range(3)),
            [],
            50,
            123456789,
            datetime.now())
```

Updating available seats causes the price to update:

```
print(F1.price)              # 10
F1.set_available_seats(30)
print(F1.price)              # 210
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great and what I want!

Answer (score 3):

Use a lambda function, then call `A["b"]` when you want the proper value:

```
>>> A={"a": 1}
>>> A["b"]= lambda: 4*A["a"]
>>> A["b"]()
4
>>> A["a"] = 5
>>> A["b"]()
20
```

Updated for the case where `A["a"]` is a list:

```
>>> A={"a": [1,2,3,4,5]}
>>> A["b"]= lambda: [4*i for i in A["a"]]
>>> A["b"]()
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```

Comment: The issue I have with this implementation is that while the syntax is nice ("just add `()` after a dictionary call"), in reality the dictionary isn't storing the value itself. It must recalculate each time. I posted an object-oriented solution which I believe better suits the problem.

Comment: @jpp Oh I agree, the overarching issue is best solved with an OOP solution. Definitely an XY problem. +1 to your approach!