# Can I reference a dict value on dict creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary and I want to set the value of `netdev["ipv6"]["addr"]` with the former declared `netdev["ipv6"]["prefix"]`.

Is there any elegant way to do this "on-the-fly" or do I have to do this outside of the dict declaration with the known mechanisms like `dict.update()`, ... ?

```
net_dev = {
    "link_name": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "10.80.0.1",
        "mask": "255.255.255.0",
    },
    "ipv6": {
        "prefix": "2001:db8:0:1::",
        "addr": <HERE_THE_PREFIX_IS_USED> + "1234:1",
        "mask": "64",
        "prefix_range": "2001:db8:0:100::",
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the dict doesn't exist at the time you are defining it, I'm not sure that you'd be able to reference an element within this dict until it has been created.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468401/can-you-set-a-dictionary-value-dependant-on-another-dictionary-entry for a similar problem.

Comment: What should be the desired behaviour in case the value of `prefix` changes?

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but you could just define a second varialbe `prefix` before initialising the dict and use it in the values for both keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No! You can use `f-strings` (available in Python-3.6+) to automatically format strings based on already available variables which in this case can be `netdev["ipv6"]["prefix"]`. If You're not aware of the value of `netdev["ipv6"]["prefix"]` before creating the dictionary there will be no way to do this on the fly, (at least in Cpyhon implementation or in general at Python-level). However, there might be some hacks to create a custom dictionary which re-formats the value of the intended keys as is mentioned here:  [Can you set a dictionary value dependant on another dictionary entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468401/can-you-set-a-dictionary-value-dependant-on-another-dictionary-entry).

```
PREFIX = previously_defined_prefix
net_dev = {
    "link_name": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "10.80.0.1",
        "mask": "255.255.255.0",
    },
    "ipv6": {
        "prefix": PREFIX,
        "addr": f"{PREFIX}1234:1",
        "mask": "64",
        "prefix_range": "2001:db8:0:100::",
    }
}
```

In this case `PREFIX` is a variable defined in the same name space as the `net_dev` dictionary.

In you're using 3.6- versions instead of f-string approach you can simple use `str.format()` or just + operator:

```
PREFIX = previously_defined_prefix
net_dev = {
    "link_name": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "10.80.0.1",
        "mask": "255.255.255.0",
    },
    "ipv6": {
        "prefix": PREFIX,
        "addr": "{}1234:1".format(PREFIX),  # PREFIX + "1234:1"
        "mask": "64",
        "prefix_range": "2001:db8:0:100::",
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. There is no `HERE_THE_PREFIX_IS_USED` variable available, as the prefix is only being assigned to `net_dev['ipv6']['prefix']` (which as a name binding does not exist either when the dict is being evaluated).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think OP wants a dynamic link. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468401/can-you-set-a-dictionary-value-dependant-on-another-dictionary-entry) which, IMO, is not recommended.

Comment: @AKX That's right, I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: @Kasramvd I accept your answer. Since I use python3.5 could you please provide a snippet without f-strings for completion's sake? Something like PREFIX + "1234:1"

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this that doesn't involve a separate variable each time for everything you want to refer back to. Python won't allow you to make an assignment during dictionary creation, so for example, this won't work (although I think it should):

```
my_dictionary = {
  'foo': (b = 'foo'),
  'foobar': b + 'bar'
}
```

But what you can do is have a helper function that overcomes this limitation. You can store this in another py file and import it.

```
cache_dictionary = {}
def cache_value(key, value=None):
    if value is not None:
        cache_dictionary[key] = value
    return cache_dictionary[key]
```

By using that, you can basically do what you want:

```
net_dev = {
    "link_name": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "10.80.0.1",
        "mask": "255.255.255.0",
    },
    "ipv6": {
        "prefix": cache_value("prefix", "2001:db8:0:1::"),
        "addr": cache_value("prefix") + "1234:1",
        "mask": "64",
        "prefix_range": "2001:db8:0:100::",
    }
}
```

At least this way is more "like" functional programming and doesn't require additional lines of code, so to speak. For example, it would allow you to create and pass this dictionary to a function all at once, which other approaches don't allow.

It's not functional programming in the pure sense, becuase it has an intentional side effect, and indeed that's the whole point, but I guess to control that side effect, you could add a reset boolean argument if you were using this for multiple dictionaries and wanted to clear it at the top of a new dictionary initialization.